# Remote desktop user print to another user printer

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing

I have windows server 2003. What permissions is required, to user `bob` can print on printer who is attached to computer where sits `alice`. Of course, booth users are connected to server.
At this moment i have user `bob` in `Power operators` group. But i want to allow only print to another users printers.
If i put user in `printer operators` group, then that user does'n see other printers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER (based on the assumption they were on the same network)**

On Alice's computer, share out the printer (right click the printer and choose Share).  Set permissions if you want or leave it so that everyone can print to it.

On Bob's computer, add a shared printer and for the path choose `\\nameofalicecomputer\printersharename`  --  you can also simply browse to the path by going to start, run, and then typing `\\nameofalicecomputer` and hit enter.  Then right click the printer in the new Explorer window and choose "Connect".

Make sure you have the proper drivers as needed during the printer install.

**NEW ANSWER**

I honestly don't think this is possible with redirected printers and isn't ideal regardless.  You would require both Bob and Alice to be connected to the terminal server at the same time for it to work.  Bob would need elevated rights on the server to see other's redirected printers which isn't smart.

Your better option would be to look at sharing out Alice's printer on the web or simply using email/ftp/webfilesharing to get the print job from Bob to Alice for Alice to print locally.

Comment: This is not solution. User Alice is about 200km away from user Bob.

Comment: It is the solution, it doesn't matter how far away the person is...

Comment: Users are connecting to remote desktop server from different places. So, to use printer sharing, i must put users in one network via VPN. Users must print only from remote desktop server. So, printer sharing is worse solution to this case.

Comment: My apologies...I finally understand your question.  The wording is strange, but now I understand...you want Bob to be able to print to Alice's printer from within his RDP session to the TS Server.  I will create a new answer as this answer was based on them all being on the same network.

Comment: I added user bob to administrator group and now bob can print to any printer.